# Login con CURL y PHP al SII (Servicio impuestos internos de Chile)

Tags: php, curl

Tengo un código fuente que he estado probando para lograr acceso al Sistema de impuestos de Chile con cUrl en php, pero no logro que funcione, pues siempre me arroja el error 500.

El formulario de acceso está en la siguiente URL. 
https://zeusr.sii.cl//AUT2000/InicioAutenticacion/IngresoRutClave.html

El curl debería enviar la contraseña y el usuario (rut) como POST al action https://zeusr.sii.cl/cgi_AUT2000/CAutInicio.cgi

```
 <?php
    $ch = curl_init();
    $cookie = "cookies.txt";
    $userAgent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:31.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/31.0';
    $url = 'https://zeusr.sii.cl/cgi_AUT2000/CAutInicio.cgi';
    $post_data = array(
        'rutcntr' => '11.111.111-0',
        'password' => 'clave',
        'clave'    => 'clave',
        'rut'      => '11.111.111-0',
        'referencia' => 'http://www.sii.cl',
        'dv'         => '0'
    );


    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_data);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,$userAgent);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE,$cookie);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR,$cookie);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE,$cookie);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION,1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER,0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,-1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, 'https://zeusr.sii.cl//AUT2000/InicioAutenticacion/IngresoRutClave.html');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, getcwd() . "/cert/DigiCertHighAssuranceEVRootCA.crt");


    $result  = curl_exec($ch);
    $err     = curl_error($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    if ($err) 
     {
        echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
     }
    else
     {
        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($result);
        echo "</pre>";
     }
?>
```

He probado sin usar el certificado y cambiando varios de los parámetros del Curl, sin éxito. También los datos del post, colocando el rut con y sin el dígito verificador (último digito del RUT) pero El error 500  persiste.

Agradezco su ayuda, porque la verdad me estoy rompiendo la cabeza con algo que debía hacer en una tarde y llevo 3 días.

ACTUALIZACIÓN: He cambiado a 1 el valor de CURLOPT_HEADER

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER,1);

y ahora muestra más detalles en el error

HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
Date: Mon, 22 Apr 2019 20:49:21 GMT
Server: Apache
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Content-Security-Policy: default-src https: data: 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Length: 9
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1

Error 500

Comment: Un 500 es un error no controlado del servidor por lo que mas que un problema de tu petición es un problema del propio SII que tiene un bug.

Comment: Gracias @jdev, sin embargo, puedo acceder al SII con mi navegador sin problema. El asunto es que requiero automatizar el proceso de extracción de una data y para ello debo loguearme.

Answer (score 0):

Estuve verificando el formulario y tienes un parámetro de mas "password" claro esto no creo que te cause problema pero el parámetro "rut" debes enviarlo sin caracteres especiales osea solo números y sin el dígito verificador ya que este va en el parámetro "dv" 
quedado algo así:

```html
 $post_data = array(
    'rutcntr' => '11.111.111-0',
    'clave'    => 'clave',
    'rut'      => '11111111',
    'referencia' => 'http://www.sii.cl',
    'dv'         => '0'
);
```

Comment: Gracias @ruben rodiguez

Comment: Para servirte. pero si mi respuesta te ayudo no me vendría mal que marcaras mi respuesta como correcta y me dieran esos puntos :).

Comment: Gracias @ruben-rodiguez. Hice la prueba cambiando el rut y el dv, pero continúa arrojando el error 500.

Comment: Considero que si los datos del post fuesen incorrectos, arrojaría un error diferente y no un 500

Comment: eso depende de como este hecho las cosas en el servidor si pasas un parámetro con formato incorrecto por ejemplo pasas un alfanumérico y se espera un numero puede ocasionar ese error si no se contemplo esa validación

Comment: puedes darme una mano amigo? Estoy atorado en esto y no he logrado avanzar. Estaré agradecido si te tomas unos minutos más para probar el código y proponer mejoras.

Comment: Estimado, estoy intentando acceder pero aún no logro, ¿sigue funcionando esto? <!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: null --> <!-- language: lang-html --> $post_data = array( 'rutcntr' => '11.111.111-0', 'clave' => 'clave', 'rut' => '11111111', 'referencia' => 'http://www.sii.cl', 'dv' => '0' ); <!-- end snippet -->

Answer (score 0):

Despues de varias pruebas logre realizar el login, la clave es enviar los parámetros por GET, se puede realizar el login con certificado o usuario y clave.

use la libreria http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/

```
$cookiesAuth = new \GuzzleHttp\Cookie\CookieJar();       
$clientAuth = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();

$clientAuth->request('GET','https://herculesr.sii.cl/cgi_AUT2000/CAutInicio.cgi', [
        'cert' => ['RUTA CERTIFICADO', 'CLAVE'],
        'query' => [
            'rutcntr' => 'RUT-DV',
            'rut' => 'RUT',
            'referencia' => 'https://www.sii.cl',
            'dv' => 'DV',
        ],
        'cookies' => $cookiesAuth
        ]);
```

EL certificado tiene que estar en formato PEM, se puede transfromar desde pfx usando el comando:

```
  openssl pkcs12 -in cert.pfx -out cert.pem
```

Para usar usuario y clave la petición seria

```
$cookiesAuth = new \GuzzleHttp\Cookie\CookieJar();       
$clientAuth = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();

$clientAuth->request('GET','https://herculesr.sii.cl/cgi_AUT2000/CAutInicio.cgi', [
    'query' => [
        'rutcntr' => 'RUT-DV',
        'rut' => 'RUT',
        'referencia' => 'https://www.sii.cl',
        'dv' => 'DV',
        'clave' => 'CLAVE'
    ],
    'cookies' => $cookiesAuth
    ]);
```

En ambos casos de guardan las cookies en la variable $cookiesAuth, la cual debemos usar para descargar los archivos que requieren autentificación.